# xcode 9.2 Assest catalog issue

Tags: xcode, xcode9-beta, xcode9.2

In one of my app I am facing this issue in Xcode 9.2. I have created my project in Xcode 8.3 and when I am running in Xcode 9.2 it shows me error like

> Failed to find device type for  System content for
>   IBCocoaTouchFramework-ElevenAndLater
>    scaleFactor=2x
>
> Failure Reason: Could not find a suitable device type for the idiom
>
> I am using Xcode 9.2 (Version 9.2 (9C40b)).I am not able to identify
>   problem.

It gives me error in assist catalog Any one have any idea ??

Comment: Seems like [a bug/internal error](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/76989) of some kind... Did you try restarting Xcode/your Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this gets you well

1. Try to clear your derived data.
2. Try to completely restart your computer after downloading the new Simulator runtimes within Xcode for things to start working correctly again.

cheers :)